# Using xbox controller to calculate angle of elevation

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I am trying to calculate angle of elevation when using a xbox controller. To grab the coordinates, I use sharpDx Nuget package. My code is as below

```
        // Instantiate the joystick
        var joystick = new Joystick(directInput, joystickGuid);


        // Set BufferSize in order to use buffered data.
        joystick.Properties.BufferSize = 128;

        // Acquire the joystick
        joystick.Acquire();

        while (true)
        {
            joystick.Poll();
            var data = joystick.GetBufferedData();
            foreach (var state1 in data)
            {
                if (state1.Offset == JoystickOffset.X)
                {
                    int s = state1.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

I am really new to this. I really don't understand when my control is in the while loop, and I move the analog handle of the xbox, I get a huge array in 'data' with a array size between 60 and 70. I am then running a for loop to get each element in 'state1'. There are multiple values of

```
X,
Y,
RotationX,
RotationY
```

Now to calculate the angle I need X and Y. Should I use the last values of X and Y?

Please help

Comment: The buffer is a collection of recently reported values used to smooth the data, so that you don't get widely varying values (i.e. spikes) as input. Ideally, you should set `BufferSize` to something smaller (test values out) and average out the data in the buffer you actually need. Something like `float avgX = data.Sum() / data.Length;`

Comment: Why would you average? Won't that give a wrong result?

Comment: Because a sensor doesn't necessarily return smooth values. The buffer stores the last retrieved values which depends on the frequency that the sensor reports to the controller's microcontroller. Averaging helps "smooth" out the sensor data for any large variances. A small buffer size (about 32) will contain values retrieved in the last millisecond or so, which shouldn't cause input lag or inaccuracies. If you don't want to use buffered data, set `BufferSize` to `0` and use current state instead.

Comment: Thanks. To calculate angle of elevation do I just do Math.TanA(AverageY/AverageX)?

Comment: Yes. I'd recommend you use `Math.Atan2` instead to avoid division by zero exceptions.